# cocos2d png transparency issues

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

This question was asked before but the solutions did not work on my side.

My png for a simple ball looks like this:

[image]

I saved it without the white bg and with a transparent bg.

Why is the white showing up in the corners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how your are initializing your EAGLView. To support alpha transparency you should use a pixelFormat like `kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8`. Your code could look like:

```
EAGLView* glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];
```

You could try and use this png file instead of your own just to check if it might be a problem related to the png:

[image]

Comment: thx, this improved my overall image quality but the ball image is still with no transparency

Comment: the only thing I can imagine is that the png is not in the right format... transparency should work out of the box...

Comment: I would say, use a good program to create the png... what program have you used?

Comment: I used the older photoshop cs2

Comment: well, the problem is definitely in your png. Try and use gimp to create your png files, maybe it will work better.